# iOS mysterious black 1px line

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, user-interface

as the title says there's a very small black line crossing my navigation (also on real device):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDapm.png

iOS: 7

Comment: You need to pose a lot more info about your app setup before we can hazard a guess as to what's causing it. How are you structuring your view controller hierarchy? Are you using a navigation controller? Are you running on iOS 6 or 7? Are you using auto-layout? Are you laying out your views for iPhone 4 but displaying on iPhone 5? Do you set any view's layer.borderWidth to 1 anywhere?

Comment: Nobody can tell you that from just an image, so I have a few questions... Is this new behaviour or has is it this way from when you created it? Is it iOS version specific? What kind of control are we seeing? Is it derived from a standard UI component or is it completely customized? What does the view hierarchy looks like?

Comment: thanks Duncan. It's running on iOS7, laying out for iPhone 4 but viewed on iPhone 5. The different views are managed by the tab bar controller on the bottom. There are no views's layer.borderWith set to 1. Please tell me if you need any other information. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is caused by the new "feature" of iOS 7 which adds a shadow image on your TabBar. You can remove it using `[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];`